# jquery find img is returning undefined in special case

Tags: jquery

to describe my case, here's what I have:

javascript code:

```
$("#tf_zoom").live("click",function() {

    console.log($("#dynam").attr("src"));
}
```

here I get the value in the first time but after the slider changes the image I get **undefined**

I also tried:

```
console.log($(this).find("img").attr("src"));
```

but this one is not working at all.

html code:

```
<div id="tf_thumbs" class="tf_thumbs">
            <span id="tf_zoom" class="tf_zoom"></span>
            <img id="dynam" src="http://localhost/mala/assets/uploads/files/c9ab2-1.jpg" alt="Thumb1"/>
        </div>
```

the problem as I mentioned is that the slider changes the image and modifies the `img` tag to a new `src` attribute.

so what should I do.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you change the image? Do you modify the `src` attribute or substitute the entire `IMG` tag ? However, `$(this).find("img")` returns an array, while `attr` has to be called on single elements of it.

Comment: `console.log($(this).find("img").attr("src"));` inside `$("#tf_zoom").live("click",function() {` will never find the image tag as `"#tf_zoom` is the `span` tag which is not the parent of the image tag but a sibling.

Comment: @Jackopo - it just changes the src of the img tag

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - so what should I do if you can suggest plz

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: Your code is working fine if the image tag is being replaced as `live` takes care of the dynamics. See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bkU6/) using your code and a button to remove and add a new image tag, clicking your span still works.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - yes I see now I changed it to `.tf_thumbs` and now it's working ... stupid mistake from me
please post it as an answer so I can credit you

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: I wasn't sure what code you are actualy using. Using `console.log($("#dynam").attr("src"));` as you posted in the original code works fine every time as you see in the fiddle. I didn't know that the selector in live was the issue. You should post the code change you made that solved your issue as an answer and after a few days you can accept your own answer :) It is perfectly valid to do so.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - yes I know ... but as I said you told me that the parent of the image is not `tf_zoom` but `tf_thumbs` so that's why I solved it :)

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan What version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @François Wahl mentioned in his comment that I am using `#tf_zoom` as a parent for my image tag which is where I went wrong. so, I edited my code to use `.tf_thumbs` as the parent of my image tag and now it's working.

```
 $("#tf_zoom").live("click",function() {

    var n = $(".tf_thumbs").find("img").attr("src");
    //var imagespathes = {};
    //console.log($(".tf_thumbs").find("img").attr("src"));
    var modelid = n.substr(43); 


    $.post("models/get_gallery", { "modelid": modelid },
  function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        var imagespathes = $(data).map(function(key, url){
        return({ href: '<?php echo base_url();?>assets/uploads/files/' + url });
      });
      console.log(imagespathes);
  $.fancybox.open(imagespathes);
  }, "json");

            });
```

Comment: ahhh ... Mahmoud alramadan +1

Comment: @N̨ul̕L͑P̯͍̭ȏͣ͛iƞer - thnx